# Pause R script to input a filename

Tags: r, function, input

I have an R script that does some simple elaboration of data in .CSV files and I want to be able to input a filename from keyboard each time.

The system I am using at the moment is first define a function ans save it as "usr_filename.R":

```
usr.filename <- function() 
{ 
  readline("Please enter filename: ")
}
data.filename <- usr.filename()
```

And then call it from within my script:

```
#Input filename
    source("usr_filename.R")
```

This system works, but only as long as the script is run line by line in R Studio; if I try to run the whole script at once by selecting it all and clicking "Run", the result is:

```
usr.filename
function() 
{ 
  readline("Please enter filename: ")
}
```

So I tried using a different function, with readLines:

```
usr.filename2 <- function() 
{ 
  data.filename <- readLines(prompt="Please enter filename: ", n=-1)
}
```

But also this solution does not work. Anyone can help me resolving this problem?

R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) - Rstudio: Version 0.98.501 - Windows 7 Professional 32bit SP1

Comment: Is this specific to RStudio? Did you try it in the standard R GUI?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the `file.choose()` function to select a file?

Comment: I'll investigate `file.choose()`, thanks for the tip.